# Neo4j Cypher join group by having result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query in SQL and I am trying to convert to cypher

```
select *, sum(quantity) as sum_qty from table1 inner join table2 
on table1.t_id = table2.t_id_hd 
group by table1.t_id 
having sum_qty = table2.total_qty
```

The Cypher query I have so far is this

```
MATCH (a:table1)-[:parent]-(b:table2) 
WITH a.t_id, sum(a.quantity) as sum_qty, b
WHERE sum_qty = b.total_qty
RETURN a.t_id, b.t_id_hd
```

This doesn't quite work because there seems to be duplicate `b.t_id_hd`

Comment: Is that your actual and entire Cypher query? `quantity` is not defined. Also, in what way is there duplication?

Comment: But in your SQL it's the same thing, you should have multiples `tables2` items because you are doing a `group by` on the `table1`. And your `HAVING` is not clear because you are working on a non-aggregated field (`table2.total_qty`).

Comment: @logisima my having is correct. I am using the aggregated field `sum_qty`  and checking if it is equal to a column in table2 which has the total. Moreover, I ran the above SQL in all RDBMS and it works.

Comment: but there are multiples table2 items, so I don't know how RDBMS react to that and if there is a universal behaviour (take the first, check all or any ?)